# Bash for loop sometimes clips beginning of statement.

Tags: bash

I have a for loop, below,

```
for d in */; do
        echo "importing $d"
        python ../src/import_gtfs_to_sql.py $d nocopy  | psql -q gtfs
done
```

Most of the time it runs fine, but some executions within this loop are not getting fully printed out. For example, with `set -vx` I see the following:

```
hon ../src/import_gtfs_to_sql.py $d nocopy  | psql -q gtfs
+ hon ../src/import_gtfs_to_sql.py google_transit_subway/ nocopy
+ psql -q gtfs
./load.sh: line 54: hon: command not found
```

Is there a reason why Bash is not executing the whole statement?

Additional info:

```
#bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
#uname -a
Linux osgeolive 3.13.0-83-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 00:25:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Whole script is [here](https://github.com/laidig/gtfs-transfer-matrix/blob/master/load.sh).

Comment: I've only seen this when you edited the file while Bash was reading commands from it.

Comment: As an aside, you should generally use double quotes around any variable which may contain a file name; so `python ... "$d" nocopy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tripleee was on the right track. This only occurred when the script was open in an editor and may have been modified while running.